# My Action won't work with HTTP POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am having issues with trying to pass data from a js file to an Action in my MVC Controller. This is my controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [CustomAuthorize(Roles.Administrator, Roles.ContextOwner, Roles.DataOwner, Roles.DataSteward)]
    public JsonResult SaveChangesOnGrid(int id, string json)
    {
        var codeViewModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CodeViewModel[]>(json);

        var error = string.Empty;
        CodeViewModel newViewModel = null;

        foreach (var viewModel in codeViewModels)
        {
            viewModel.CodeListId = id;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                error = codeService.Validate(viewModel);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
                {
                    newViewModel = codeService.SaveToStage(viewModel);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                error = "Could not save";
            }
        }

        if (id > 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            // notify
            var codeList = codeListService.GetCurrentCodeListById(id);
            notifyGroup.NotifyDataOwnerGroup(codeList);
        }

        return Json(new
        {
            error,
            newViewModel
        });
    }
```

When I use the HTTPPOst annotation I can no longer get to it anymore. I am trying to access the Action using a button on my view. I have tried 2 different methods and neither work.

```
<a id="review_btn" class="btn btn-primary" href='@Url.Action("SaveChangesOnGrid", "Code", new {id = Model.CodeListId })'>Submit for Review</a>
```

**EDIT:** The HTML out put of the button is

```
<div class="btn-group offset10" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px">
        <a id="review_btn" class="btn btn-primary" href='/ReferenceData.Web/Code/SaveChangesOnGrid/13'>Submit for Review</a>
</div>
```

In my JS file I have a function that tries to pass a JSon array to my controller action **EDIT** Ajax updated: There is now an internal server error Http 500 when the button is pressed. When I check the network package in my developer tools it shows the HTTP packet with the JSON packet[image: Screenshot of HTTP info]

```
    function rowsToJson(obj) {
    var selRowIds = $("#CodeGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');

    if (selRowIds.length > 0) {

        var rowData = jQuery('#CodeGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', selRowIds[0]);
        var selectedRowsData = [{ "Code": rowData.Code, "ParentCode": rowData.ParentId, "Name": rowData.Name, "Description": rowData.Description }];

        for (var i = 1; i < selRowIds.length; i++) {

            rowData = jQuery('#CodeGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', selRowIds[i]);

            selectedRowsData.push({ "CodeId": rowData.CodeId, "Code": rowData.Code, "ParentCode": rowData.ParentId, "Name": rowData.Name, "Description": rowData.Description });
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: window.g_baseUrl + 'Code/SaveChangesOnGrid',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(selectedRowsData),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            async: true,
            processData: false
        });

        //$(obj).attr('href', obj.href + "?json=" + JSON.stringify(selectedRowsData));
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Please select a code");
        return false;
    }
};

$(function () {
    $('#review_btn').click(function () {
        if (confirm('These Selected Changes will be submitted for approval \n\n Are you sure you wish to proceed?')) {
            return rowsToJson(this);
        } else {
            $('#CodeGrid').jqGrid('resetSelection');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

You can see from what I have commented out I have tried using AJAX and just appending the JSON as a string onto the end of the URL.

Using AJAX with the href removed from the button I get an error 500. If I leave the href in when I debug to my controller the json parameter is null.

If I append the JSON array to the end of the URL with the HTTPPost annotation the json parameter is null. When I remove the annotation the JSON is passed through, but as I step through the code an error is thrown telling me about a security issue involving JSON and Get

I would prefer to use Ajax if possible because it avoids the data being visible to the user in the URL. But I really just want to get something working.

Comment: Any Console errors? What is the final html output of this: url: '@Url.Action("SaveChangesOnGrid", "CodeController", new {id = Model.CodeListId })',

Comment: @RealityDysfunction Hi just added the HTML output for the button, there are no console errors until teh button is pressed when I am trying to use the AJAX call

Comment: While debugging, which line in your controller code is the error thrown?

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedRowsData))` show you? Does it match your action signature?

Comment: @Jasen the output of stringify is [{"Code":"BRA","ParentCode":" ","Name":"BRA","Description":"Brazil"}]. Using the AJAX the code doesn't get to the controller. The error in the controller is from using GET and I want to avoid that after reading the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are posting does not match your action signature. You can see the exception details on the *Preview* or *Response* tab of the debug console.

Your action signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveChangesOnGrid(int id, string json)
```

Your POST is sending:

```
var selectedRowsData = [{ "Code": rowData.Code, "ParentCode": rowData.ParentId, "Name": rowData.Name, "Description": rowData.Description }];
selectedRowsData.push({ "CodeId": rowData.CodeId, "Code": rowData.Code, "ParentCode": rowData.ParentId, "Name": rowData.Name, "Description": rowData.Description });

$.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify(selectedRowsData)
});
```

What is expected is:

```
var selectedRowsData = [{ "Code": "", "ParentCode": "", "Name": "", "Description": "" }];

$.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify({ "id": "1", "json": JSON.stringify(selectedRowsData) });
});
```

That's probably not what you intend so...

**Try this instead**

Let the framework do the binding and deserialization.

```
var selectedRowsData = [];
for (var i = 1; i < selRowIds.length; i++) {
    rowData = jQuery('#CodeGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', selRowIds[i]);
    selectedRowsData.push({ "CodeId": rowData.CodeId, "Code": rowData.Code, "ParentCode": rowData.ParentId, "Name": rowData.Name, "Description": rowData.Description });
}

$.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify(selectedRowsData)
});
```

Now create a model that mirrors your JSON object. (Your `CodeViewModel`?)

```
public class Country
{
    public int CodeId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string ParentCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Change the action signature

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveChangesOnGrid(Country[] codes)
```

... then forget about manually deserializing the data.

Answer (score 1):

First, forget about using GET, it looks ugly and may fail if the JSON gets too big. 
Take a look at how the action is set up here:

[Calling WebMethod returning IList<T> from Jquery Ajax with NHibernate And MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910982/calling-webmethod-returning-ilistt-from-jquery-ajax-with-nhibernate-and-mvc)

and here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx

Try simplifying this as per above example.

I believe JSON.Stringify is required here. Also remove, the roles annotations for now until you get your code to function.