# jQuery.getJSON Call ASP.NET method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I have jQuery code to get JSON from the server:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON('Default2.aspx/GetPerson', { 'firstname': 'brian', 'lastname': 'lee' }, function (response) {
                alert(response.Age);
            });    
        });
```

Default2.aspx code :

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static String GetPerson(String firstname, String lastname)
    {
        Person p = new Person(firstname, lastname);
        return "{\"Age\":\"12\"}";
    }
```

The question is :

Why `GetPerson` method is not called from my script? I attach the debugger in `GetPerson` but it seems doesn't called.

Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: i am not sure if that is the reason, you could give the property name as data. data:{ 'firstname': 'brian', 'lastname': 'lee' }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910982/calling-webmethod-returning-ilistt-from-jquery-ajax-with-nhibernate-and-mvc. i guess you need to get rid of the webmethod.as per this post, webmethods are obsolete

Comment: I am using ASP.NET, not ASP MVC..:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WebMethod`s by default respond to `POST` rather than `GET` requests.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Default2.aspx/GetPerson',
    dataType: 'json',
    // ...
});
```

And, the request format should be JSON as well to match the `ResponseFormat`:

```
// ...
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'firstname': 'brian', 'lastname': 'lee' }),
    contentType: 'application/json'
```

---

Alternatively, a `ScriptMethod` can be configured to use `GET` instead:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
```

Though, `contentType` still needs to be set for it, so `$.getJSON()` can't be used:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Default2.aspx/GetPerson',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    // ...
});
```

And, `data` will be URL-encoded, but each value will need to be JSON-encoded before that:

```
// ...
    data: {
        firstname: JSON.stringify('brian'),
        lastname: JSON.stringify('lee')
    }
```

---

Also note that `ScriptMethod`s will wrap their response in a `{ "d": ... }` object. And, since the `return` value is a `String`, the value of `"d"` be that same unparsed `String`:

```
// ...
    success: function (response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response.d);
        alert(response.Age);
    }
```

Comment: You said `WebMethods by default respond to POST rather than GET requests.`. So how can i set WebMethod respond to GET?

Comment: @IswantoSan It is possible, though with some caveats. See my edit.